# Find all analytic bijections $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. Justify that there are no other analytic bijections besides those you found.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-functions

This is a question from a previous complex analysis qualifying exam. I'm working problems to study for my own upcoming qual. I'd like to know if my solution below is correct and complete or not. Thanks!

**Problem:**

Find all analytic bijections $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. Justify that there are no other analytic bijections besides those you found.

**Attempted Solution:**

(1) Since we're looking for analytic functions on the whole complex plane, we are considering only functions which are entire.

(2) A constant function is neither injective nor surjective, so clearly it is not a bijection. By Liouville's Theorem, any bounded entire function is constant. Thus, such a bijection must have a singularity at infinity since it is analytic everywhere else.

(3) The singularity at infinity must be either a pole or an essential singularity. If there is an essential singularity at infinity, then by the Great Picard theorem, in any neighborhood of infinity, the function attains every value in $C$ (with at most one exception), so these functions would be "infinity-to-1". Thus, not bijections.

(4) Finally, we are left with entire functions that have a pole at infinity. Any such function is a polynomial (since it can be written as a power series), but polynomials of degree $n$ are $n$-to-1 functions. Thus, the only functions that are 1-to-1 are 1st degree polynomials or linear functions of the form $f(z) = \alpha z + \beta$ with $\alpha \neq 0$.

**Update to include suggestion by @Greg Martin:**

(5) We have shown that if an entire function is a bijection, then it is linear. It remains only to show that if a function is linear, then it is an analytic bijection. We know that any polynomial is analytic.

We have that a function $f(z)=\alpha z + \beta, \; \alpha\neq 0$ is injective if $f(z)=f(w) \implies z=w$. This is straightforward as
$$ \alpha z + \beta = \alpha w + \beta \implies z = w $$
by simply subtracting off $\beta$ and dividing both sides by $\alpha \neq 0$.

Then we have that $f$ is surjective if, for every $w \in \mathbb{C}$, there exists a $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=w$. One can see that
$$\alpha z + \beta = w \quad \implies z = \frac{w-\beta}{\alpha}, \; \alpha\neq 0. $$

Thus, for any $w$ there exists such a $z$, and $f(z)$ is an analytic bijection.

Comment: You've proved "if analytic bijection, then linear", but you should also prove (the easy direction) "if linear, then analytic bijection". Other than that, it looks good!

Comment: "...  of the form $f(z)=\alpha z+\beta$"  **with $\alpha\ne 0$**

Comment: You certainly do not need Great Picard. That's hugely overkill. Use Casorati-Weierstrass, whose proof you certainly should know.

Comment: The proof you gave is the standard one.

Comment: Alternatively, you can show any automorphism of the Riemann Sphere is a Mobius transformation via either via the Galois Correspondence or directly (a standard direct argument found in most textbooks requiring nothing but the existence of Laurent Series can be found [here](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/automorphisms-of-the-riemann-sphere)).

Comment: Specifically, Given a Mobius transform $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, we must then ask when $\infty$ gets mapped to $\infty$ (so it is merely a lift of an automorphism of $\mathbb C$). By continuity we have $f(\infty) = \frac{a}{c}$, so either $a = \infty$ or $c = 0$. We exclude the former case since we must have $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb C$ to get a Mobius transform (I'm being a bit loose here, and one could work in projective coordinates to be more careful), so $c = 0$ so any linear automorphism of $\mathbb C$ is linear.

Comment: @TedShifrin But Casorati-Weierstrass only gives me that we get arbitrarily close to every value in $\mathbb{C}$ at least once... so how does that give me that it's definitely not 1-to-1?

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you, that would be more clear!

Comment: Every neighborhood of $\infty$ has dense image. What does this say about the values taken on by the function on the unit disk?

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for your suggestion! I've updated my proof to include this.